# Create multiple calculated fields which are referenced to other columns, based on conditions using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to create multiple calculated fields which are referenced to other columns, based on conditions using Pandas

**Data**

```
ID       status         used
AA       False          3
BB       True           2
```

**Desired**

```
ID       status         used     new
AA       False          3        0.6  
BB       True           2        2
```

**Doing**

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['used'] * 0.2 if row['status'] == 
                                       'False' else row['used'] * 1, axis = 1)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated
The following is not calculating off of the correct field

Comment: make the `status` column to be of `bool` type, that would be natural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': ['AA', 'BB'],
    'status': [False, True],
    'used': [3, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['used'] * 0.2 if row['status'] == False else row['used'] * 1, axis=1)

print(df)
```

I can create your desired output:

```
   ID  status  used  new
0  AA   False     3  0.6
1  BB    True     2  2.0
```